# Imputation: which method is this

Tags: data-imputation

I'm working on a paper on machine learning. Suppose I have three classes (A, B, C). Suppose now I have a model that outputs

```
Y = [A, ?, ? , A, ?, ?, B, ?, ?, C, ?, ?, A]
```

The question marks indicate missing values. These missing values always come in pairs of two with always a classification before and after each pair. I now want to impute it such that it becomes

```
Y = [A, A, A , A, A, B, B, B, C, C, C, A, A]
```

the missing value becomes the left value if that isn't a question mark or becomes the right value if that isn't a question mark. I'm now simply wondering wht this specific method is called. I found [this link](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/seven-ways-to-make-up-data-common-methods-to-imputing-missing-data/) describing seven ways of imputation but what I did did not seem seem to be among them. Closest imputation method I believe was cold deck, but I'm not certain. I simply need the official technique/name for a paper.

EDIT: The order of the elements in `Y` is of utmost importance! They are not random! It's about classifying time-series where classes often follow up each other a long time and only sometimes switch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the methods in your linked post do *not* consider is the ordering in your data. Your method only makes sense because there is a "left" and a "right" that is *meaningful*. If you had unordered data, you would be able to permute it in any way without changing its semantics - and then your proposed method would not make sense.

The method you are thinking about is commonly called "last observation carried forward" (LOCF) and "next observation carried backward" (NOCB). For instance, this is implemented in the `data.table::locf()` function in R, which fills `NA` observations.